# pgfplotstable selecting numeric columns or multiple columns by index

Tags: tables, formatting, pgfplotstable

Hi two questions in one:

I haven't been able to figure out the answer from the manual: I have a table of data with strings in the first column:

I'd like to apply some key-values (e.g. fonts by sign) to the numeric columns only. Is there a quick way of doing so?

something like

```
every numeric column/.style={fonts by sign={}{\color{red}}
```

or

```
every columns nos {2,3,4}/.style={fonts by sign={}{\color{red}}
```

MWE to work on below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=false]{
a & 1 & 2\\
b & 2 & -2\\
c & 3 & 0.5\\
}\atable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[fixed,
zerofill,
fonts by sign={}{\color{red}},
every first column/.style={string type}]\atable
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
columns/1/.style={{fonts by sign={}{\color{red}}},dec sep align},
```

for each column, Here, `dec sep align` is used to align the numbers at the decimal point.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=false]{
a & 1 & 2\\
b & 2 & -2\\
c & 3 & 0.5\\
}\atable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[fixed,
zerofill,
columns/1/.style={{fonts by sign={}{\color{red}}},dec sep align},
columns/2/.style={{fonts by sign={}{\color{red}}},dec sep align},
every first column/.style={string type}]\atable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar, I'm looking for something that deals with multiple columns collectively. I have a large number of columns and doing this individually would make the tex file very unwieldy.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha I don't think that feature is available! :(. There are `every even column/.style` and `every odd column/.style` though, but they will conflict with your first column.

Comment: I think you may be right, but felt I'd try asking anyway. This may be another feature request for @ChristianFeuersanger. I might try and write a macro for it if I ever figure out how they work. If I do I'll post it here.