# pgfplotstable: How to highlight row and column of a cell with special content

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, highlighting

If I say `string replace={x}{\cellcolor{pink}x}` a cell with content 'x' gets highlighted. 
But how to highlight the row and the column of 'x' too?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, x, i
j, k, l
}\mytable

\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\section{Highlight a Cell with special Content}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
string replace={x}{\cellcolor{pink}x}
]{\mytable}

\section{Highlight row, column too?}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
string replace={x}{\cellcolor{pink}x}
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148141/197451

Comment: @jsbibra Not bad, but I fear this is not "cell content sensitive". :()

Comment: A solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559044/pgfplotstable-how-to-use-the-read-out-row-column-value-for-styles