# pgfkeys / pgfplotstable: How to get (and save) row- and column-number of a cell with special content

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, pgfkeys

I have a cell with special content, say 'x'. 
I could find 'x' with `string replace`. 
But how can I get and save the *row-* and the *column-number* of that cell?
With `\pgfplotstablerow` and `\pgfplotstablecol`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, x, i
j, k, l
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
string replace={x}{x
%\pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfplotstablerow}{\rowno} % works not
%\pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfplotstablecol}{\colno} % not that easy
 }
]{\mytable}

x is in row no. ? and column no. ?
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your purpose with these `two` numbers?

Comment: Good question. The idea is to use these number for highlight rows / cols ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557748/pgfplotstable-how-to-highlight-row-and-column-of-a-cell-with-special-content ). I tried to use @Henri Menke solution there without succes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty close to a duplicate of this question of yours on TeXwelt, even though you never accepted my answer:

> pgfplotstable: Auf 'column name' mit 'pgfkeysgetvalue' zugreifen
>
> https://texwelt.de/fragen/23473

At least in my answer I showed the principle of how this could be done in general, so it comes as no surprise that I will again use `postproc cell content` to access the cell content to perform the comparison.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, x, i
j, k, l
}\mytable

\def\literalx{x}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
postproc cell content/.code={%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\literalx
    \xdef\remembercol{\pgfplotstablecol}%
    \xdef\rememberrow{\pgfplotstablerow}%
  \fi
}]{\mytable}

x is in row no.~\rememberrow\ and column no.~\remembercol.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thx, that works fine here. I tried to solve https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557748/pgfplotstable-how-to-highlight-row-and-column-of-a-cell-with-special-content with that. I think this should be possible. Could you have a look on it?