# pgfplotstable: How to use the read out row- (column-) value for styles

Tags: pgfplotstable, colortbl

I want to color a row (column) from a cell with special content, e.g. 'x'.

I tried to use 
`every nth row={\rememberrow}{before row=\rowcolor{orange}}, % WORKS NOT!` 
in [the solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558938/46023).

```
\xdef\remembercol{\pgfplotstablecol}%
\xdef\rememberrow{\pgfplotstablerow}%
```

expands correctly after the `pgfplotstabletypeset`, but not while the typeset.

What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, x, i
j, k, l
}\mytable

\def\literalx{x}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
postproc cell content/.code={%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\literalx
    \xdef\remembercol{\pgfplotstablecol}%
    \xdef\rememberrow{\pgfplotstablerow}%
  \fi
}, 
%every nth row={\rememberrow}{before row=\rowcolor{orange}}, % WORKS NOT!
]{\mytable}

\textbf{Works:} x is in row no.~\rememberrow\ and column no.~\remembercol.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With savebox and newcommand it works:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, x, i
j, k, l
}\mytable

\colorlet{CellColor}{red}
\colorlet{RowColor}{orange}
\colorlet{ColColor}{pink}

\def\literalx{x}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{   myhighlights/.style={}    }
\newcommand\MyTable{%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[myhighlights,
postproc cell content/.code={%
  \def\temp{##1}% <--- !   '##',    not '#'
  \ifx\temp\literalx
    \xdef\remembercol{\pgfplotstablecol}%
    \xdef\rememberrow{\pgfplotstablerow}%
  \fi
}, 
]{\mytable}%
}

\newsavebox{\Mybox}
\savebox{\Mybox}{\MyTable}

\section{Raw Table}
\usebox{\Mybox}

\section{Read out row and column -- works}
x is in row no.~\rememberrow\ and column no.~\remembercol.


\section{Typeset highlighted Table -- works as well}
\pgfplotstableset{myhighlights/.style={%% =======
% Highlight Row:
every row no \rememberrow/.style={
before row={\rowcolor{RowColor}}        }, 
% Highlight Column:
every col no \remembercol/.style={
column type/.add={>{\columncolor{ColColor}}}{}       }, 
% Highlight Cell
every row no \rememberrow\space column no \remembercol/.style={  
@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{CellColor}}{},      },% <--- !  '\space'
}%% =======
}
\MyTable
\end{document}
```